# how to retrieve all records from sequelize PostgreSQL except a specific value?

Tags: postgresql, except, sequelize-cli

I want to retrieve all the records except a specific value, I tried the below query but I am not getting the required output.

```
db.owner.findAll({ exclude: { model : models.owner.name: 'jack'}, 
    include: [{ model: models.customer, as: 'customers' }]
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with this one

```
db.owner.findAll({({
    where : { name: {ne: 'jack'}},
    include: [{ model: models.customer, as: 'customers' }]
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer works for me:

```
db.owner.findAll({ 
  where: {name: { $not: 'jack'}},
  include: [{ model: models.customer, as: 'customers' }]
});
```